# How do I use templates and content selectors together?

Tags: javascript, templates, polymer, shadow-dom

Suppose I have the following element:

```
<polymer-element name="foo-bar" noscript>
  <template>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <content select="h1"></content>
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

How can I supply the content with templates like so:

```
<foo-bar>
  <template if="{{ model === 'dog' }}">
    <h1>Woof</h1>
  </template>

  <template if="{{ model === 'cat' }}">
    <h1>Meow</h1>
  </template>
</foo-bar>
```

As of now, it appears the content selectors are evaluated before the templates; so there's no h1's in the DOM when `<content select='h1'>` tries to find them. I suspect there's a way for me to do this (even if it requires some hacking). Or perhaps I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: Uhh, this might work already (I might have a typo in my original code). Will confirm later.

Comment: It looks right to me, just check thay your {{}} databinding are either in a polymer-element, or an autobinding template.

Failing that, it might be your model === 'cat' isn't a recognized polymer expression.